# django authentification error

Tags: python, django, url, view

I am running into an error where I am logging in a user and it is supposed to redirect to details.html but instead the the url gets parsed but it stays at login.html. I believe there is a problem with the views.py. If there is a better way of doing this please let me know. Thanks

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/")
def patientDetails(request, personalInfo_id):
current_user = request.user
if personalInfo_id == current_user.id:
    return render(request, 'personalInfo/details.html', {})
else:
    return render(request, 'personalInfo/login.html', {})

@login_required(login_url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/")
def after_login(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/personalInfo/details/%d/'%request.user.id)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^details/$', views.after_login, name='patient'),
url(r'^details/(?P<personalInfo_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.patientDetails),
]
```

[Picture of what is going wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGJYW.png)

Comment: `personalInfo_id` is a string.

Comment: If you only let users see their own details, then there's no need to use a URL like `/details/<id>/` - just use `/details/` as the URL.

Comment: I actually had that before and did not work. Any chance you would know why?

Comment: No idea why - "did not work" is not enough information to tell what the problem is.